# XCode 5 storyboard toolbar

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In XCode 5 storyboard (and maybe previous versions) I can drag a UIToolbar to the black area that shows underneath the view, so I have a view, first responder, toolbar and exit button.

But I can't seem to find any documentation that states the purpose of adding a toolbar there rather than in the view itself.

Does anyone know what this is for?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag anything you like in there really, not just a toolbar.
The purpose is to have those objects instantiated along with the main view so that they are accessible from the ViewController (hook them up via IBOutlets).